# How to connect fields in the Serializer (DjangoRestFramework)?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a read access to SQL-legacy DB. Suppose in the DB I have two tables: **Treatment and TreatmentType**. 
In the Treatment table, I have `patientID (int), date (text), treatmentType (int)`. In the TreatmentType table, I have `code(int) and meaning (Text)`.
The **Treatment.treatmentType** is the code for finding the **meaning** in the TreatmentType table.

During the first migration, I use a built-in method:`inspectdb` from `django`, and I get something like this:

```
class TreatmentType(models.Model):
    index = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.IntegerField(db_column='Code', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    meaning = models.TextField(db_column='Meaning', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'TreatmentType'


class Treatment(models.Model):
    index = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.IntegerField(db_column='PATIENT', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    date = models.TextField(db_column='DATE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
    treatmenttype = models.IntegerField(db_column='TREATTYPE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Treatment'
```

From the model, I want to have a REST API for getting the list of treatment with an extra column TreatmentMeaning. I use DjangoRestFramework to create the **serializers** for me:

```
class TreatmentModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    meaning = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_meaning')

    def get_meaning(self, instance):
        meaning = TreatmentType.objects.get(code=instance.treatmenttype).meaning
        return meaning

    class Meta:
        model = Treatment
        fields = [
            'patient',
            'date',
            'meaning',
        ]
```

It works fine. but I'm a bit skeptical about this. Are there any other alternative ways to do it correctly (in a more efficient way)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a couple of the comments, `inspectdb` is only a guess. In particular it has failed to find the foreign key between Treatment and TreatmentType, so it's up to you to make that change yourself.

Update the `treatmenttype` field on Treatment as follows:

```
treatmenttype = models.ForeignKey('TreatmentType', db_column='TREATTYPE', to_field='code', blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, as well as being able to follow that foreign key automatically in your own code - eg via `my_treatment.treatmenttype.meaning` - you can use the [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) in your serializer to automatically get the meaning value:

```
class TreatmentModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    treatmenttype = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='meaning'
```

There are a couple of other field types that should be updated; the `index` fields are probably meant to be AutoFields, and the `date` should be a DateField.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do something like this. Both of them unrelated table in the DB... Does it mean I can only join them manually @Daniel Roseman?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If `TREATTYPE` is an integer representing the relevant row in the TreatmentType table, it is a foreign key.

Comment: Ahh, how do I specify that the relevant field is not the `index`, but the `code` field?

Comment: Use the [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) argument; updated.